# Edges look wrong when compositing layers with blur and transparency

Tags: transparency, compositing-nodes, motion-blur

I'm trying to composite layers from an animation I made with Blender in After Effects. The problem I'm running into is that the motion-blurred edges are either receding, or becoming discolored, depending on the settings I choose.

In AE, I'm using a 32bit OpenEXR Multilayer file and the EXtractoR plug-in to select the layers. I'm also using Color Profile Converter.

For whatever reason, the edges look more accurate when UnMult is checked, but the colors get messed up.

Frankly, I'm not sure if the problem is happening at the Blender or AE level. I assume it has something to do with associated(pre-multiplied)/unassociated(straight) alpha channels.

Pictured below is the combined render from Blender, which I'm using as the basis to compare my composite to. Beneath that is how my composite looks without, and then with UnMult checked.

[image: Combined render straight from Blender with all objects turned on.]
[image: Composite of foreground and background renders in Adobe After Effects with UnMult unchecked.]
[image: Composite of foreground and background renders in Adobe After Effects with UnMult checked.]

Edit: Here's two additional images, showing what the composite looks like in Blender when using the Alpha Over compositing node. As you can see, it looks very much like the two pictures above, only the colors on the edges are correct (with convert premul off). If I could get it to look like this in After Effects, that would be terrific!

[image: Composite in Blender using the Alpha Over node with "Convert Premul" turned on.]
[image: Composite in Blender using the Alpha Over node with "Convert Premul" turned off.]

Comment: I suspect this is indeed a problem on how the app you use cannot deal with associated alpha correctly. Do the composite directly in blender or use an app that can do the job correctly, like Natron, Fusion, Nuke etc.

Comment: In blender you don't need to use the premultiply button when using alpha over. Blender will handle Associated alpha correctly.

Comment: I'm saving to OpenEXR Multilayer directly from the render window i.e. im not actually using that node in my final save, I just used it to demonstrate where the source of the problem might be and to provide a comparison between blender and AE @susu

Comment: Blender will export fully compliant EXR with proper associated alpha. Is what I'm getting at. I stopped using Adobe products long time ago so I can't help you on that front.